# How do I move wordpress from a subfolder to root directory - domain.com/wordpress to domain.com

Tags: wordpress

I followed this guide on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/oLsA2kj_bMU)
to install wordpress on my Ubuntu 16.04 Linode server. When I finished the video guide my domain.com address showed the apache2 default page, while domain.com/wordpress is where the homepage was located.

I don't really know anything about linux. I tried this setup because it was the cheapest way to use a VPS.

Can someone please hold my hand on how to get my homepage to domain.com instead of domain.com/wordpress.

I would really appreciate the help.

---

I solved the issue. I rebuilt within Linode, then used Linodes guide to get started, but Godaddys guide for the virtual host. If like me you get stuck on step 5 hit ESC then :wq!

Comment: Open a terminal and run this: `ls /var/www/html` and post the result into your post

Comment: index.html wordpress

Comment: Two issues you haven't place this `<ip_address>  domain.com` in `/etc/hosts`, and no `<domain.conf>` file in the `sites-available` folder... Note this is how it's on a linux desktop and should be the same on a VPS

Comment: Please contact support for further help `Linode` should help you better

Comment: I did, they said they said configuring and troubleshooting individual services on a user's Linode is generally outside of their scope of support

Comment: Lets me see if I can help run `echo $HOSTNAME` and give the result

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do that :

```
cd /var/www/
mv html/wordpress .
rm -r html
mv wordpress html
```

And that's it, your wordpress is installed on mydomain.com/

Comment: when I try the opposite, move a site from `html` into `wordpress`, apache forbids access to the site.

Comment: Thanks. It was sweet and crisp.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can change the configuration of you'r apache2.
Set web site data root directory like this.

Move to folder /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Open `000-default.conf`with you'r text editor as super user.
I used vim here, but your system doesnt have vim installed,
you can use nano text editor, just replace command vim with nano when ever i used it.

```
sudo vim 000-default.conf
```

File looks something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Error page is just the index telling about the situation of not being connected
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

All you have to do is to change this line.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

For example it could look like this.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/WordPress
```

After editing the file you have to restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

**Remember this way you change you'r apache default data root to that folder.
Right and best way is to set up new virtual host configuration for you word press site.**

**BETTER WAY**
If you want to do that, for example if you want to have more sites in future you can do this.

Again get to folder /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Create new file as super user named by you'r site **and add to end .conf**
Example,

```
sudo vim MyWordpress.com.conf
```

The write following lines inside, and replace all text with **
with you'r info.
for exmaple *FILE PATH TO YOUR INDEX.hmlt file* with /var/www/Mywordpress

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName **YOUR DOMAIN OR IP**
    ServerAlias **REPEAT YOUR DOMAIN**
    DocumentRoot **FILE PATH TO YOUR INDEX.hmlt file**
    ErrorLog **FILE PATH TO YOUR error.log file**
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After you have save the file, you have to run command to active your site.
Replace *YOUR FILE NAME* with the name of file you just creted.
Example `www.myFirstSite.com.conf`

```
sudo a2ensite *YOUR FILE NAME*
```

Then you have to restart apache and you are done.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you have more websites running at the same time in future, you can repeat the process above and your domains will point to right site.

Let me know if i was able to help you :)
Feel free to ask any more info.

Best regards,
Vis25